# How do I start conky when ubuntu starts up?

Tags: conky, startup-applications

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 and installed the Conky system monitor, and start it with the `conky` command. I added this code on startup-applications but nothing works. How do I start conky when my Ubuntu starts up? Is it possible to start multiple Conky themes on startup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added the following command as a startup application:

```
conky -p 30
```

and it works for me.

Apparently the desktop has to have initialized before conky starts and the 30 second delay allows for this.